# Is there a way to have a NavigationView object without a hamburger menu (so it is persistent on the side of the window)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, navigationview

I want a menu on the side of the screen that is persistent but can't work out how to do it.(without the hamburger)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to hide the burger button, you can set the property in the `NavigationView`:

`IsPaneToggleButtonVisible="False"`

If you want to hide the back button, you can set like:

`IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed"`

If you want to fix the side pane, Here are two suggestions:

1. If your application minimum version is **17763** or higher:
   Set the property `PaneDisplayMode="Left" IsPaneOpen="True"`
2. If your application minimun version is **17134**:
   Bind event `PaneClosing` on NavigationView:

```cs
private void NavigationView_PaneClosing(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewPaneClosingEventArgs args)
{
    args.Cancel = true;
}
```

Best regards.